# How make pictureboxes of a transparent Panel to appear?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, transparency

I am making a 2D game in windows form and I have a problem... 
So,  I have a Panel where all the "Ground" Tiles (PictureBox[]) are... But instead of just setting the PictureBox.Image, i need to have another Panel above the "Ground Tiles" one, so it can looks like the player is behind something... But that panel needs to be transparent, and its Picture boxes need to appear to make the effect, yet it doesnt... The reason why I put the Tiles (PictureBox) inside a Panel, it is because i want to make the illusion that the camera is focused on the player (meaning the player doesnt really moves, its the Panels that moves).

Can anyone help me please? I know it looks complex... Sorry...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using World;

namespace World
{

  public partial class LoadWorld : Form
  {

    public int TileSizeX = 30;
    public int TileSizeY = 30;
    public int TileT = 2500;
    public int TileX = 49;
    public int TileY = 49
    //Here's the problematic panel
    public Panel PropPanel = new Panel();
    public PictureBox[] WorldTile = new PictureBox[2500];
    public PictureBox[] PropTile = new PictureBox[2500];
    public static Dictionary<PictureBox, int[]> tileProp = new Dictionary<PictureBox, int[]>();
    public LoadWorld()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void LoadWorld_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //settings of the PropPanel
        PropPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        PropPanel.BringToFront();
        PropPanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        PropPanel.Visible = true;
        PropPanel.Name = "PropPanel";
        PropPanel.TabIndex = 0;
        int valueA = 0;
        int valueX = 0;
        int valueY = 0;
        foreach (PictureBox pictureBoxValue in WorldTile)
        {
            if(valueY < TileY)
            {
                if(valueX < TileX)
                {
                    WorldTile[valueA] = new PictureBox()
                    {
                        Size = new Size(TileSizeX, TileSizeY),
                        Location = new Point(valueX * 30, valueY * 30),
                        BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/null.png"),
                        Visible = true,
                        Name = "tile" + valueA
                    };
                    WorldMap.Controls.Add(WorldTile[valueA]);
                    valueA = valueA + 1;
                    valueX = valueX + 1;
                }
                else if(valueX == TileX)
                {
                    WorldTile[valueA] = new PictureBox()
                    {
                        Size = new Size(TileSizeX, TileSizeY),
                        Location = new Point(valueX * 30, valueY * 30),
                        BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/null.png"),
                        Visible = true,
                        Name = "tile" + valueA,
                     };
                    WorldMap.Controls.Add(WorldTile[valueA]);
                    valueA = valueA + 1;
                    valueY = valueY + 1;
                    valueX = 0;
                }
            }
            else if(valueY == TileY)
            {
                if (valueX < TileX)
                {
                    WorldTile[valueA] = new PictureBox()
                    {
                        Size = new Size(TileSizeX, TileSizeY),
                        Location = new Point(valueX * 30, valueY * 30),
                        BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/null.png"),
                        Visible = true,
                        Name = "tile" + valueA,
                    };
                    WorldMap.Controls.Add(WorldTile[valueA]);
                    valueX = valueX + 1;
                    valueA = valueA + 1;
                }
                else if (valueX == TileX)
                {
                    WorldTile[valueA] = new PictureBox()
                    {
                        Size = new Size(TileSizeX, TileSizeY),
                        Location = new Point(valueX * 30, valueY * 30),
                        BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/null.png"),
                        Visible = true,
                        Name = "tile" + valueA,

                    };
                    WorldMap.Controls.Add(WorldTile[valueA]);
                }
            }
        }
        SetGroundTiles();
        SetPropTiles();
    }

    public void SetGroundTiles()
    {
        SGT(1, "grass");
        SGT(2, "DirtPathVSideL");
        SGT(3, "DirtPathCenter");
        SGT(4, "DirtPathVSideR");

        //Road
        SGT(9, "SidewalkMiddle");
        SGT(10, "Asphalt");
        SGT(11, "Asphalt");
        SGT(12, "Asphalt2YL");
        SGT(13, "Asphalt");
        SGT(14, "Asphalt");
        SGT(15, "GrassConcreteHL");
        SGT(59, "SidewalkMiddle");
        SGT(60, "Asphalt");
        SGT(61, "Asphalt");
        SGT(62, "Asphalt2YL");
        SGT(63, "Asphalt");
        SGT(64, "Asphalt");
        SGT(65, "GrassConcreteHL");
        SGT(109, "SidewalkMiddle");
        SGT(110, "Asphalt");
        SGT(111, "Asphalt");
        SGT(112, "Asphalt2YL");
        SGT(113, "Asphalt");
        SGT(114, "Asphalt");
        SGT(115, "GrassConcreteHL");

    }
    public void SetPropTiles()
    {
        SPT(9, "SmallTree2", true, false);
        SPT(60, "SmallTree1", false, true);
    }
    public void SGT (int valueA, string texture)
    {
        WorldTile[valueA].BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/" + texture + ".png");
    }
    public void SPT(int valueA, string texture, bool Collide, bool IsOverlaying)
    {

        PropTile[valueA] = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "Panel" + valueA,
            Image = new Bitmap("Sprites/" + texture + ".png"),
            Location = WorldTile[valueA].Location,
            Size = WorldTile[valueA].Size,
            Visible = true,
            BackColor = Color.Transparent,

        };
        //Where PropPanel is being used
        PropTile[valueA].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        PropPanel.BringToFront();
        PropPanel.Controls.Add(PropTile[valueA]);
        WorldMap.Controls.Add(PropPanel);


    }
  }
}
```

Its like overlaying a transparent panel on another panel...
i have tried to put the 2nd panel transparent but its images just didnt appear.

[view of the tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0DoV.png)

[This may help you to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jEkp.png)

what i want to do is basically 3 layers of panel...

PropTextures (like if the player was behind something)

---

Player Texture / PropTextures (Collision with objects)

---

Ground Textures (where the player can or not walk)

Comment: WinForms transparency means "control takes the background color of the control that contains it". It's not real transparency, it won't show the graphical data below/behind it. And while Controls do work with the alpha-channel of images to not-show or transparently show pixels within an image, it's rendered on top of the background color. Winforms rendering is not made to do that and btw. it's not optimized to show data that way, so your games performance will probably be horrible anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transparency, the way you are trying to use it, is not provided by the PictureBox control.  I don't think you're going to have much luck if you continue with your current approach.

So here is a tip for an *alternate approach*.  If you're having difficulty doing this with PictureBox controls and such, then you could do the rendering yourself.  Create a UserControl that is DoubleBuffered, and in the Paint event, for each sprite, call Graphics.DrawImage to render each image to the correct spot.  The nice thing about this technique is that you will get proper alpha-correct compositing when drawing the sprites this way.  Just be sure to sort them so that you draw them from back to front and "paint over" the background sprites using the foreground sprites.

Comment: can you give a link or an exemple to do that please?